# Cannot form weak reference to instance of class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm getting the error `Cannot form weak reference to instance (0x15919e00) of class TestClass. It is possible that this object was over-released, or is in the process of deallocation.` with the bit of code below.

If I remove the `addObserver` and `removeObserver` lines, my code doesn't crash. I'm not really sure why that's happening though. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance for the help!

```
class TestClass: NSObject {

     lazy var tableView: UITableView = {

         let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
         tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
         tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 52.0
         tableView.delegate = self
         tableView.dataSource = self

         let nib = UINib(nibName: "CustomCell", bundle: nil)
         tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customCell")

         tableView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myPath", options:nil, context: nil)

         return tableView
     }()

     deinit {
         tableView.removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: "myPath") 
     }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Lazy variables and weak references aren't really coming together tought. I think the problem lies within the tableView being declared as lazy var. Change it to read only variable and you should be fine...